# how to update stored hh:mm value to hh:mm:ss in mysql database, the column datatype is String?

Tags: java, mysql

i have stored data in the database with String datatype as
10:56,
10:30:89

like this, now is it possible to convert all the data with hh:mm:ss format i.e.
10:30:89

Please help me here

Comment: 89 seconds in a minute - ? what does 89 represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database is holding on a varchar column data related to time in two different formats `hh:mm` and `hh:mm:ss` and you want to unify all the records to have the same format you need to identify the records in `hh:mm` and add a `':00'` to them at the end.

You can do that with a query similar to that one:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE
SET MYCOLUMN = CONCAT(MYCOLUMN, ':00')
WHERE MYCOLUMN NOT LIKE '%:%:%'
```